# Jquery setTimeout not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have the following jQuery code--

```
$('div#mid_number_of_mail').mouseover(function () {

    setTimeout(function () {
        $('div.element_popup' ,this).stop().animate({
            opacity : '1'
        }, 250, 'linear', function() { });
    }, 5000);

});
```

But I don't know why it is not working properly. Can someone help me with this code?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In what way is it not working? What does firebugs say?

Comment: I don't know as I'm new to jQuery. I just don't see the element fading and fading out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `this` is `window` not the div with the given id.

`this` is context sensitive based on *how the function is called*.

Since the function is called via `setTimout`, it doesn't have an object context so uses the default object: `window`.

You want `this` as it is for the mouseover function, so you need to save a copy of it in a different variable.

```
$('div#mid_number_of_mail').mouseover(function () {
  var that = this; // Take the this from this context and keep it for other functions
  setTimeout(function () {
                  $('div.element_popup', that).stop().animate({
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use :

```
setTimeout( function(ele) {}, 2000, $(this) );
```

In your "ele", you'll have a reference to "$(this)".